# transitive add_custom_command dependencies not carried over

Tags: c++, cmake

I have some protobuf files which are in a directory outside of my cmake project (they live in a root directory *next to* the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` where our main CMakeLists.txt file is).

```
root/
+--- src/
|    +--- CMakeLists.txt            # main CMakeLists
|    +--- messages/
|         +--- CMakeLists.txt       # protocol generation CMakeLists
|         +--- base/
|              +--- header.pb.cc
|              +--- header.pb.h
+--- protocols/
     +--- base/
     |    +--- header.proto         # protocol definitions
     .    .
```

My goal is to create a custom_command which will generate the `.pb.cc` and `.pb.h` files and link them into a library for use in my project.

So in the above example, `root/src/messages/base/header.pb.cc` is created from `root/protocols/base/header.proto`.

#### Protobuf generation:

I have created a function (`protoc`) which loops over a list of protobuf `.proto` source files, and calls [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) to invoke the protobuf compiler on each file.

```
function(protoc SRCS_OUT HDRS_OUT)

    set(options)
    set(values  CPP_OUT CWD)
    set(lists   PROTO)
    cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "${options}" "${values}" "${lists}" "${ARGN}")

    set(GENERATED_SRCS)
    set(GENERATED_HDRS)

    foreach(FILE ${ARG_PROTO})

        # find the absolute path to the .proto file
        get_filename_component(ABS_FILE ${FILE} ABSOLUTE)

        # replace source-dir with dest-dir and generate the path where the 
        #  .pb.cc and .pb.h files will be created
        string(REPLACE ${ARG_CWD} ${ARG_CPP_OUT} PROTO_DEST ${ABS_FILE})

        get_filename_component(FILE_WE  ${PROTO_DEST} NAME_WE)
        get_filename_component(DEST_DIR ${PROTO_DEST} DIRECTORY)

        set(GENERATED_SRC "${DEST_DIR}/${FILE_WE}.pb.cc")
        set(GENERATED_HDR "${DEST_DIR}/${FILE_WE}.pb.h")

        # run the protoc compiler on the .proto file, specifying the generated 
        #  .pb.cc and .pb.h files as OUTPUT, and the .proto file as the
        #  MAIN_DEPENDENCY
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT
                ${GENERATED_SRC}
                ${GENERATED_HDR}

            COMMAND
                protoc

            ARGS
                --cpp_out ${ARG_CPP_OUT} ${ABS_FILE}

            WORKING_DIRECTORY
                ${ARG_CWD}

            MAIN_DEPENDENCY
                ${ABS_FILE}

            COMMENT
                "Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on ${FILE}"

            VERBATIM
            )

        set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED_SRC} ${GENERATED_HDR} 
            PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

        list(APPEND GENERATED_SRCS ${GENERATED_SRC})
        list(APPEND GENERATED_HDRS ${GENERATED_HDR})

    endforeach()

    set(${SRCS_OUT} ${GENERATED_SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)
    set(${HDRS_OUT} ${GENERATED_HDRS} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

Note that I have specified the dependencies between the `.pb.cc` and `.pb.h` files and the `.proto` files:

- `OUTPUT`: I specify the full path to the generated `.pb.cc` and `.pb.h` files
- `MAIN_DEPENDENCY`: I specify the full path to the `.proto` file

I then use the above `protoc` function to create a library consisting of the generated `.pb.cc` files:

**`root/src/messages/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
get_filename_component(PROTOCOLS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../protocols" ABSOLUTE)

protoc(
    PROTO_SRCS
    PROTO_HDRS

    PROTO
        ${PROTOCOLS_DIR}/base/header.proto

    CWD
        ${PROTOCOLS_DIR}

    CPP_OUT
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )

add_library(
    msg_base
    STATIC
    ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS}
    )
```

As such, the command to `protoc` will have as its `PROTO` argument

- `/home/steve/root/protocols/messages/base/header.proto`

and `msg_base` will have as its sources

- `/home/steve/root/src/messages/base/header.pb.cc`
- `/home/steve/root/src/messages/base/header.pb.h`

My expectation is that now any target which links `msg_base` will **transitively** have a dependency on the `.proto` files

```
target -> msg_base -> header.pb.cc -> header.proto
```

eg:

```
add_executable(foo ${FOO_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(foo msg_base) # transitive dependency on header.proto
```

#### The problem:

On occasion `header.proto` will be out of date, but `foo` will link against an old version of `msg_base`.

`msg_base` won't be rebuilt with the new `header.pb.cc` files before `foo` is linked (with an out of date `msg_base`).

**Questions:**

- Is my use of paths to files which are **not** in the same directory as the CMakeLists.txt (both the `.proto` files and the `.pb.cc` etc files) allowed?

I ask this because the help for [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) does make reference to targets created in the same directory, and I'm wondering if this falls foul of that?

- Note also that we are using parallel builds

Comment: You are using `ninja` as a build environment?

Comment: @Florian no I'm using "Unix Makefiles"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research led me to a post on the cmake wiki titled "[How can I add a dependency to a source file which is generated in a subdirectory?](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_add_a_dependency_to_a_source_file_which_is_generated_in_a_subdirectory.3F)"

It turns out that cmake currently doesn't know how to link generated files as dependencies to targets **in a different directory**.

That sounds very much like it is the root cause of this issue.

There is an open [bug report / feature request](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14633) for this, but as of writing it is still open.

The "fix" is to move the creation of each library which includes the generated protobuf files into the subdirectory where those files are generated.

That is, move the creation of `msg_base` from `root/src/messages/CMakeLists.txt` to `root/src/messages/base/CMakeLists.txt`

The resulting tree will look as follows:

```
root/
+--- src/
|    +--- CMakeLists.txt            # main CMakeLists
|    +--- messages/
|         +--- base/
|              +--- CMakeLists.txt  # protocol generation CMakeLists
|              +--- header.pb.cc
|              +--- header.pb.h
+--- protocols/
     +--- base/
     |    +--- header.proto         # protocol definitions
     .    .
```